# Null check doesn't recognize that nullable value is handled by conditional statement

Tags: typescript

Basically I've been using a workaround for a null check in a node application.

Consider this:

```
import { Page } from 'puppeteer'; // Type definition

export interface IOptions {
    // ... some options
    waitFor: number | null;
}

const defaultOptions = {
    // ... some default options
    waitFor: null
};

export const load = async (pageInstance: Page, url: string, options: IOptions = defaultOptions): Promise<Page> => {
    const { timeout, waitFor } = options;

    if (!waitFor) {
        // ... do some stuff that doesn't include Puppeteer's Page waitFor() method
    } else {
        try {
            const workAroundWaitFor = waitFor || 0; // redundant workaround necessary for null check

            return await pageInstance.waitFor(workAroundWaitFor);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
};
```

Essentially the type `Page` and it's method `waitFor` accepts `string | number | function` but **not** `null` or `undefined`. Indeed, it shouldn't and I wouldn't want it to. However, the Typescript will refuse to compile my application unless this `workAroundWaitFor` is included (pretending to offer a numeric fallback).

This seems like something people would run into frequently, but I've failed to locate the correct approach. I'm pretty new to Typescript so if my Googling has failed big time, or if I'm simply failing to approach this with idiomatic logic please forgive me. The Node application I'm working on has gotten big enough that Typescript makes an enormous difference, and for that same reason I'd like to make sure I'm making the most of it.

Comment: I just copied your code and everything compiles/works like it should (except I removed unused timeout, changed the returned Promise to <any>). I'm at typescript@2.9.2 and you?